# autoclick <button class="next active">

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I need help making a Tampermonkey script that triggers

```html
<button class="next active"><span>›</span></button>
```

repeatedly.

Current code:

```js
$(function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName("next active").click();
        document.querySelector("input[type='next active']").click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("a.NAMEOFTHEBUTTON").trigger('click');
        },10);
    });
```

Comment: Hello there.. Welcome to StackOverflow.. This question doesn't seem to show any attempt to resolve the problem, or any sort of research effort. Please include what ever the things that you have tried so far, and then may be we could help...

Comment: A selector that starts with `a` is an anchor, not a button. And wanting to repeat and event via click is a good sign you're either trying to cheat or abuse something you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *collection*, not an *element.

Also, the element there has *two* classes: one class is `next`, and the other is `active`. Classes are separated by spaces; you can't select `"next active"` like that because it's not a single class name.

Better to use `querySelector` when only selecting a single element, rather than to use a method that returns the collection and then select the first element in the collection.

If you want to *repeatedly* click, then you should use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` (or make the `setTimeout` function call itself recursively).

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button[class="next active"]');

// example code to show click trigger:
button.onclick = () => console.log('click');

setInterval(() => button.click(), 500);
```

```html
<button class="next active"><span>›</span></button>
```